# Using Telegram API for my android application

Tags: android, api, telegram

- I have downloaded the code from [this repository](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)
- I edit `"src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/BuildVars.java"` with my api_id and api_hash values.

What are the next steps ?

What folders should I add to my project from [this link](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) and in that place ?
As I call API methods ?

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to use raw Telegram API. Try some wrapper, like https://notificatio.me

Comment: This website is dead

Comment: What the notificatio? Is there alternatives now?

Comment: @DynoCris notificatio was a simple REST API, that allows you to send messages to Telegram w/o using their API. Unfortunately, the project is closed. I suggest you to use Telegram BOT API to send messages to users in telegram. Hope it helps!